# "ReferenceError: process is not defined" when connecting and saving to Mongoose in TypeScript from React component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongoose, referenceerror

When commenting out the `sendScore()` call from App.tsx, the error disappears. Mongoose is listed as dependency (`"mongoose": "^6.3.1",`) in my package.json file. `process` is a Node.js global variable.

Console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.1490 (browser.umd.js:2:1)
    at r (browser.umd.js:2:1)
    ...
    ./src/lib/sendScore.ts  @   sendScore.ts:1
    ...
    ./src/App.tsx   @   index.js:1
```

App.tsx:

```
// ...
import { sendScore } from './lib/sendScore'

function App() {
  // ...
  const onEnter = () => {
    // ...
    sendScore(solutionIndex, solution, guesses, false, isHardMode)
  }
}

export default App
```

sendScore.ts:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const password = '<PASSWORD>'
const url = `mongodb+srv://username:${password}@cluster0.xrcmw.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

mongoose.connect(url)
const scoreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    solutionIndex: Number,
    solution: String,
    guesses: [String],
    lost: Boolean,
    isHardMode: Boolean,
})

const Score = mongoose.model('Score', scoreSchema)

export const sendScore = (solutionIndex: number, solution: string, guesses: string[], lost: boolean, isHardMode: boolean) => {
    const score = new Score({
        solutionIndex: solutionIndex,
        solution: solution,
        guesses: guesses,
        lost: lost,
        isHardMode: isHardMode,
    })
    
    score.save().then(() => {
        console.log('Score sent')
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you put which file process is in the code?

Comment: `process` isn't written to anywhere and is usually accessed as `process.env`. These accesses are in index.html and some other TypeScript files (not sendScore.ts).